# Align bootstrap-cards contents

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

As you can see from the image, the last line of text is not aligned with the others (of the other bootstrap-cards). Logically this fact depends mainly on the size of the upper text.

How can I ensure that regardless of the length of the text the three fundamental parts are always aligned? Considering also that the title (the first line of text) could be on multiple lines (very extreme case).

This is the code for only one card:

```
<div class='col-lg-4' style='cursor: pointer; padding-bottom: 15px;'>
    <div style='height: 377.59px;' class='card mb-3' style='border: 1px solid #33cdc6;'>
        <img style='height:185.59px; width: 100%;' class='card-img-top' src='#' alt='Card image cap'>
        <div class='card-body'>
            <h5 class='card-title' style='color: #293a44;'>TITOLO</h5>
            <p class='card-text'>Breve descrizione</p>
            <p class='card-text'>
                <span class='h5 text-muted'>Montepremi</span>";
                <small style='padding-left: 125px;' class='text-muted'>data</small>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: actual status]

Comment: You'll have to set a fixed height to that `<small>` element because you sometimes have a string that is two lines high. Or you can wrap the element with a `<div class="my-auto">` to center the content along the y-axis.

Comment: Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51860518/bootstrap-4-cards-vertical-alignment-body-with-variable-header-line-rows/51862891#51862891

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would either have to tweak the CSS Flexbox on the card to get your elements to line up. Or you could use Bootstrap's `card-footer` class which will place any content at the bottom. Then you could modify the css properties on the card footer to make it look however you want.

```
<div class='col-lg-4' style='cursor: pointer; padding-bottom: 15px;'>
<div style='height: 377.59px;' class='card mb-3' style='border: 1px solid #33cdc6;'>
    <img style='height:185.59px; width: 100%;' class='card-img-top' src='#' alt='Card image cap'>
    <div class='card-body'>
        <h5 class='card-title' style='color: #293a44;'>TITOLO</h5>
        <p class='card-text'>Breve descrizione</p>
        <p class='card-text'>
            <span class='h5 text-muted'>Montepremi</span>";
            <small style='padding-left: 125px;' class='text-muted'>data</small>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer">
        Footer Text here
    </div>
</div>
```

This would be the easiest way in my opinion.

The flexbox method would required setting the `card-body` as `display: flex` using CSS. Then making sure the `flex-direction` is set to column and `justify-content` to space-between.

Note: The Bootstrap 4 card component is actually set to display as flex. Therefore the `card-body` is a flex item. You may run into problems. Have a play around.

For more information on [flexbox click here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).