# all divs with same height in a flexbox with at the bottom

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I have the following html to build a grid with bootstrap 4.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        here are different heights possible
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row align-items-end">
      <div class="col-lg-12 date">
        should always be at bottom (like the fourth date)
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        here are different heights possible
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row align-items-end">
      <div class="col-lg-12 date">
        should always be at bottom (like the fourth date)
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        here are different heights possible
        here are different heights possible
        here are different heights possible
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row align-items-end">
      <div class="col-lg-12 date">
        should always be at bottom (like the fourth date)
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

I want to have the date always at the bottom of the second row. Maybe the picture explains the problem better. The first three dates are not in a line with the fourth date at the bottom of the flexbox:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to equally align the content in children of *separate* flexbox parents. You can however make the columns also flexbox container using `d-flex` and then `mt-auto` (`margin-top:auto`) to push the dates to the bottom of the columns.

```
        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3 d-flex flex-column">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12">
                    here are different heights possible
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row mt-auto">
                <div class="col-lg-12 date">
                    date
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Demo: https://www.codeply.com/go/gLYW7liCfc

Also see: [bootstrap 4 cards - vertical alignment body with variable header line rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51860518/bootstrap-4-cards-vertical-alignment-body-with-variable-header-line-rows/51862891#51862891)

Answer (score 0):

You can stretch the `date` container to fill the remaining space of the row with `flex:1` and align all the content to the bottom with `align-items:flex-end` :-)

I've amended your example slightly below, you don't actually **need** to extra `.row` within the `wrapper` - the `col-lg-12` should be all you need to wrap onto next row.

I've only added the `border:white 1px solid;` so that you can see how my solution is working - you can just ignore that.

(You might need to view full screen to see the stacked elements working properly)!

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: #1D3159;
  color: white;
}

.date {
  background: #1D3159;
  color: white;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  border:white 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- just for this example -->

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3 wrapper">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      here are different heights possible
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-12 date">
      should always be at bottom (like the fourth date)
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3 wrapper">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      here are different heights possible
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-12 date">
      should always be at bottom (like the fourth date)
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3 wrapper">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      here are different heights possible here are different heights possible here are different heights possible here are different heights possible here are different heights possible
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-12 date">
      should always be at bottom (like the fourth date)
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```